# Button not working on a sine wave project in processing

Tags: button, processing, trigonometry

I'm creating a sine wave and I want the amplitude and frequency to be adjustable by mouse, so I made a button that turns this on and off. It doesn't seem to be working. The `//Button Script` part is where the button is defined, and it should work but when I click in the box while running it, it doesn't do anything, even though I have fulfilled all the conditions in the `if`.

void setup() {
        size(1600,900);
    }

```java
//Define variables.
float amp = 0.0;
float freq = 0;
int totalwavelength = 50;
int mouse = 0;


void draw(){
    background(0);
    freq = 0;

    while (freq < totalwavelength) {
        //When button is not pressed, run this script:
        if (mouse == 0) {
            fill(255);
            ellipse(freq * 50 + 20, sin(amp) * 100 + 450, 20, 20); 
            freq += 1;
            amp += 0.5;

            //Create Button
            fill(255);
            rect(800, 800, 200, 100);

            //Mouse Coordinates
            fill(255, 0, 0);
            text("X=" + mouseX, mouseX, mouseY - 10);
            text("Y=" + mouseY, mouseX, mouseY);

            //Button script
            if (mouseX >700 && mouseX < 900 && mouseY >750 && mouseY < 850 && mousePressed == true && mouse == 0) {
                mouse = 1;
            } 

            if (mouseX >700 && mouseX < 900 && mouseY >750 && mouseY < 850 && mousePressed == true && mouse == 1) {
                mouse = 0;
            } 
        }


        //When button pressed run this script:
        if (mouse == 1) {
            fill(255);
            ellipse(freq * 50 + 20, sin(amp) * 100 + 450, 20, 20); 
            freq += mouseX;
            amp += mouseY;

            //Create Button
            fill(255);
            rect(800, 800, 200, 100);

            //Button script
            if (mouseX >700 && mouseX < 900 && mouseY >750 && mouseY < 850 && 
       mousePressed == true && mouse == 0) {
                mouse = 1;
            } 

            if (mouseX >700 && mouseX < 900 && mouseY >750 && mouseY < 850 && 
                mousePressed == true && mouse == 1){
                mouse = 0;
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need to get into the habit of [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program. Add print statements to your code to figure out exactly what it's doing. For example, add a print statement inside every `if` statement, and whenever you change the `mouse` variable.

You'll find that whenever you change `mouse` to `1`, you immediately change it back to `0` in the next step. That's happening here:

```java
if (mouseX >700 && mouseX < 900 && mouseY >750 && mouseY < 850 && 
  mousePressed == true && mouse == 0) {
    mouse = 1;
    println("change mouse to 1 1");
} 
if (mouseX >700 && mouseX < 900 && mouseY >750 && mouseY < 850 && mousePressed == true && mouse == 1) {
    mouse = 0;
    println("change mouseto 0 1");
}
```

That first `if` statement changes `mouse` to `1`, and then the second `if` statement checks whether `mouse` is `1` and changes it to `0`.

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do with this `mouse` variable, but you also need to get into the habit of [breaking your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and focusing on those problems one at a time. In other words, you need to isolate your problem: get a sketch working that just prints something to the console when you press a button. If you have trouble with that, post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much!